# .htaccess Rewrite rules code isnt working correctly as suppose too

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

My rewrite rules are not working, I reviewed many sites and can't find anything. It's suppose to redirect to https://www.example.com but it's only redirecting to https://example.com only. Secondly my rewrite rules are not working as I keep getting 404 when I try to go to them. For example example.com/user/profile.php?username=Username is suppose to be example.com/users/Username

```
# COPYRIGHT 2020 BLOX CORPORATION
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)$  [NC]
        RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L
        ErrorDocument 403 /error/?errorcode=403;
        ErrorDocument 404 /error/?errorcode=404;
        ErrorDocument 500 /error/?errorcode=500;
        RewriteRule ^/account/verify$ /account/verify.php;
        RewriteRule ^/account/forgot-password/$ /account/forgot.php;
        RewriteRule ^/account/logout/$ /account/logout.php;
        RewriteRule ^/account/inbox/$ /account/inbox.php;
        RewriteRule ^/account/friends/$ /account/friends.php;
        RewriteRule ^/account/trades/$ /account/trades.php;
        RewriteRule ^/account/character/process$ /account/character-process.php;
        RewriteRule ^/account/character/$ /account/character.php;
        RewriteRule ^/account/inbox/chats/api/(.*)$ /account/inbox/ChatAPI.php?id=$1;
        RewriteRule ^/account/inbox/chats/(.*)$ /account/inbox/chat.php?id=$1;
        RewriteRule ^/account/settings/process/$ /account/edit-process.php;
        RewriteRule ^/account/settings/blocked/$ /account/edit-blocked.php;
        RewriteRule ^/account/settings/(.*)/$ /account/settings/index.php?tab=$1;
        RewriteRule ^/account/settings/$ /account/edit.php;
        RewriteRule ^/account/message/(.*)/$ /account/message.php?id=$1;
        RewriteRule ^/account/discord-verify$ /account/discord-verify.php;
        RewriteRule ^/games/(.*)/(.*)/$ /games/viewGame.php?GameId=$1&SeoName=$2;
        RewriteRule ^/games/edit/(.*)$ /games/editGame.php?GameId=$1;
        RewriteRule ^/trade/view/(.*)/$ /account/view_trade.php?id=$1;
        RewriteRule ^/trade/process/$ /trade/process.php;
        RewriteRule ^/user/(.*)/friends/$ /user/friends.php?username=$1;
        RewriteRule ^/user/(.*)/groups/$ /user/groups.php?username=$1;
        RewriteRule ^/user/suspended/$ /user/suspended.php;
        RewriteRule ^/user/trade/inventory/$ /trade/inventory.php;
        RewriteRule ^/user/trade/(.*)/$ /trade/index.php?Username=$1;
        RewriteRule ^/users/(.*)/message/$ /user/sendmessage.php?username=$1;
        RewriteRule ^/users/(.*)/backpack/fetch/(.*)/(.*)/$ /user/UserInventoryJSON.php?u=$1&t=$2&p=$3;
        RewriteRule ^/users/(.*)/backpack/fetch/(.*)/$ /user/UserInventoryJSON.php?u=$1&t=$2;
        RewriteRule ^/users/(.*)/backpack/$ /user/userInventory.php?u=$1;
        RewriteRule ^/users/(.*)/$ /user/profile.php?username=$1;
        RewriteRule ^/forum/topic/(.*)/(.*)/$ /forum/topic.php?id=$1&page=$2;
        RewriteRule ^/forum/topic/(.*)/$ /forum/topic.php?id=$1;
        RewriteRule ^/forum/thread/(.*)/(.*)/$ /forum/thread.php?id=$1&page=$2;
        RewriteRule ^/forum/thread/(.*)/$ /forum/thread.php?id=$1;
        RewriteRule ^/forum/reply/(.*)/$ /forum/reply.php?id=$1;
        RewriteRule ^/forum/new/(.*)/$ /forum/new.php?id=$1;
        RewriteRule ^/forum/movethread/(.*)/$ /forum/move.php?id=$1;
        RewriteRule ^/forum/bookmarks/$ /forum/bookmarks.php;
        RewriteRule ^/forum/my-posts/$ /forum/my-posts.php;
        RewriteRule ^/forum/drafts/$ /forum/drafts.php;
        RewriteRule ^/forum/draft/(.*)/$ /forum/view-draft.php?id=$1;
        RewriteRule ^/forum/search/$ /forum/search.php;
        RewriteRule ^/store/edit/(.*)/$ /store/edit.php?id=$1;
        RewriteRule ^/store/view/(.*)/$ /store/item.php?id=$1;
        RewriteRule ^/store/search/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/$ /store/fetch.php?sort=$1&query=$2&page=$3;
        RewriteRule ^/store/fetch/(.*)/(.*)/$ /store/fetch.php?sort=$1&page=$2;
        RewriteRule ^/store/fetch/(.*)/$ /store/fetch.php?sort=$1;
        RewriteRule ^/sign-up/forgot-old-account-pass/$ /sign-up/forgot.php;
        RewriteRule ^/groups/(.*)/create/shirt/$ /groups/create/shirt.php?id=$1;
        RewriteRule ^/groups/(.*)/create/pants/$ /groups/create/pants.php?id=$1;
        RewriteRule ^/groups/(.*)/get-members/(.*)/(.*)/$ /groups/get_members.php?id=$1&rank=$2&page=$3;
        RewriteRule ^/groups/(.*)/get-divisions/(.*)/$ /groups/get_divisions.php?id=$1&page=$2;
        RewriteRule ^/groups/(.*)/get-store/(.*)/$ /groups/get_store.php?id=$1&page=$2;
        RewriteRule ^/groups/(.*)/settings/members/(.*)/(.*)/$ /groups/settings_members.php?id=$1&rank=$2&page=$3;
        RewriteRule ^/groups/(.*)/settings/$ /groups/settings.php?id=$1;
        RewriteRule ^/groups/(.*)/(.*)/$ /groups/view.php?id=$1&seo=$2;
        RewriteRule ^/upgrade/checkout$ /upgrade/checkout.php;
        RewriteRule ^/upgrade/bits$ /upgrade/bits.php;
        RewriteRule ^/upgrade/credits$ /upgrade/credits.php;
        RewriteRule ^/search/fetch/(.*)$ /search/fetch.php?q=$1;
        RewriteRule ^/search/category/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ /search/fetchCategory.php?c=$1&&p=$2&q=$3;
        RewriteRule ^/inbox$ /inbox/index.php;
        RewriteRule ^/inbox/user/(.*)$ /inbox/chat.php?type=user&username=$1;
        RewriteRule ^/inbox/group/(.*)$ /inbox/chat.php?type=group&groupId=$1;
        RewriteRule ^/inbox/notification/(.*)$ /inbox/chat.php?type=notification&notificationId=$1;
        RewriteRule ^/inbox/group-invite/(.*)$ /inbox/acceptGroupInvite.php?code=$1;
        RewriteRule ^/inbox/view-notification/(.*)$ /inbox/viewNotification.php?id=$1;
        RewriteRule ^/api/user/get-notifications$ /API/user/GetAllNotifications.php;
        RewriteRule ^/api/user/get-unread-notifications$ /API/user/GetUnreadNotifications.php;
        RewriteRule ^/api/chats/get-chats/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ /API/chats/GetChats.php?type=$1&id=$2&p=$3;
        RewriteRule ^/api/chats/get-recent-chats$ /API/chats/GetRecentChats.php;
        RewriteRule ^/api/chats/get-chats-summary$ /API/chats/GetChatsSummary.php;
        RewriteRule ^/api/chats/get-group-chats-summary$ /API/chats/GetGroupChatsSummary.php;
        RewriteRule ^/api/chats/get-notifications-summary$ /API/chats/GetNotificationsSummary.php;
        RewriteRule ^/api/chats/check-profanity$ /API/chats/CheckProfanity.php;
        RewriteRule ^/api/chats/group/edit-group$ /API/chats/group/EditGroup.php;
        RewriteRule ^/api/chats/group/manage-members$ /API/chats/group/ManageGroupMembers.php;
        RewriteRule ^/api/chats/group/get-members$ /API/chats/group/GetMembers.php;
        RewriteRule ^/api(.*)$ /API$1;
```